# construct a lattice with a defined unitcell

Tags: plotting, physics, lattices

We can construct a base-centered tetragonal unit cell by:

```
LatticeData["CenteredTetragonal", "Image"]
```

But how can we construct a lattice by `8` of this unit cell (put them together)? For example, `4` unit cells on the top and `4` unit cells on the bottom of the lattice.

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19165/how-to-generate-a-3-d-simple-cubic-lattice-of-length-4-in-each-dimension) there is a trick for simple cubic but it does not work for may lattice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ClearAll[latticeGrid]
latticeGrid[{lattice_String, {x_, y_, z_}}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{ld = LatticeData[lattice, "Image"], lengths, 
      tuples = Tuples[Range[0, # - 1] & /@ {x, y, z}]}, 
  lengths = -Subtract @@@ CoordinateBounds @ 
      DiscretizeGraphics[ld /. ( Sphere[__]:> {})];
  Show[ld /. prim : (_Polygon | _Line | _Sphere) :> 
      Translate[prim, lengths # & /@ tuples], opts]]
```

***Examples:***

```
latticeGrid[{"CenteredTetragonal", {4, 1, 2}}, ViewPoint -> {1, -3, 1}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
latticeGrid[{"CenteredTetragonal", {2, 2, 3}}, ViewPoint -> {1, -3, 1}]
```

[image]

```
latticeGrid[{"FaceCenteredCubic", {3, 1, 3}}, ViewPoint -> {1, -3, 1}]
```

[image]

```
latticeGrid[{"TetrahedralPacking", {3, 1, 2}}, ViewPoint -> {1, -3, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Glorious!!! Wonderful!!!

Comment: Is there any possibility to change the color of unit cells? Or it is by default and cannot be changed!

Comment: @InzoBabaria, you can post-process to inject the desired styles. For example, `latticeGrid[{"FaceCenteredCubic", {3, 1, 1}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {1, -3, 1}] /. {p_Polygon :> {FaceForm[Blue], 
    EdgeForm[Cyan], p}, l__Line :> {Red, l}, s__Sphere :> {Green, s}}`.