# Draw the image of a complex region

Tags: plotting, complex

I'm working on a complex question that asks that I determine a function that maps the complement of the region $D=\{z:|z+1|\le 1\}\cup\{z: |z-1|\le 1\}$ onto the upper half plane. That is, $f$ must map the region $C\backslash D$ onto the upper half plane. Here is my proposed answer:
$$f(z)=e^{\pi(z+2)(-1+i)/(2z(1+i))}$$

And my code for the function and the region $C\backslash D$:

```
f = Function[z, Exp[Pi/2*(z + 2)*(-1 + I)/(z*(1 + I))]]
RegionPlot[(x + 1)^2 + y^2 > 1 && (x - 1)^2 + y^2 > 1, {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

If someone has a little time, could you maybe provide an easy way of shading the image of region $C\backslash D$ under the function $f$?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20634/image-of-first-quadrant-under-fz-zi-z-i together with appropriate `RegionFunction`

Comment: You've got more than 30 answers to 21 questions, accepted 2, upvoted 2. Did really only 2 answers deserve upvotes?  Why should one take his (little) time trying to help and provide nice answers to your questions?

Comment: @Artes - Worse than even me! Though, I have improved.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I don't think that SE reputation is a major advantage of spending one's time here of course, but rather gaining knowledge from others. Having said that, I expect one should acknowledge other's time and effort when getting help.

Comment: @Artes Yes! I improved my voting behavior after being prodded by you.  Thanks!  (Not that it's outstanding or anything but, certainly, an improvement.)

Comment: @MarkMcClure while your voting is not stellar, you've answered 176 questions. I think we'll make an exception, just this once. :)

Answer (score 11):

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@(Through[{Re, Im}[
      x + I y]] Boole[((x + 1)^2 + y^2 > 1 && (x - 1)^2 + y^2 > 
        1)]), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

is your domain

[image]

Your mapping:

```
f = Function[{x, y}, 
  Exp[Pi/2*(x + I y + 2)*(-1 + I)/((x + I y)*(1 + I))]];
```

maps *into* upper half plane:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@(Through[{Re, Im}[
      f[x, y]]] Boole[((x + 1)^2 + y^2 > 1 && (x - 1)^2 + y^2 > 
        1)]), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: RegionFunction is a better approach than using Boole. This uses RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,u,v},(u-1)^2+v^2>1&&(u+1)^2+v^2>1]. This seems to work more quickly and efficiently. Boole was a quickk rushed answer. I am currently in very southerly latitude and only rarely online.

Answer (score 9):

Not to steal [ubpdqn's thunder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30709/52) (he has an upvote from me), I prefer to make a dedicated function for this.

```
Clear[ComplexPlot]
SetAttributes[ComplexPlot, HoldAll];

ComplexPlot[f_, {z_Symbol, zmin_?NumericQ, zmax_?NumericQ}, 
   opts:OptionsPattern[ParametricPlot]]:=
Block[{z, u, v, ulims, vlims},
    ulims = {Min[#], Max[#]}& @ {Re[zmin], Re[zmax]};
    vlims = {Min[#], Max[#]}& @ {Im[zmin], Im[zmax]};
    With[{z = u + I v, u = {u, ##}& @@ ulims, v = {v, ##}& @@ vlims},
        ParametricPlot[{Re[f], Im[f]}, u, v, opts]
    ]
]
```

This simplifies things considerably. For instance, here is a *slight* modification of an [example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0i1m5ycpu-sg7) in the documentation:

```
ComplexPlot[z + 1/z, {z, -1/2 - 1/2 I, 1/2 + 1/2 I}, PlotRange -> 5, 
   MeshStyle -> {Orange, Green}]
```

[image]

Note: it uses the real and imaginary parts of the limits to generate the limits to plot over. There is no checking, at the moment, to determine if this actually generates a rectangle in the complex plane, or not.

Comment: Shouldn't `vlims` be the imaginary part? As it stands `ulims==vlims`. Can this function be used to map arbitrary domains, e.g. `Abs[z]<1`, or just rectangular domains? (+1)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Arbitrary domains require a bit more work, so let me think on it. Of course, the real method is to use [`domainPlot`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7359/52) by Simon Woods.