# Complex number plot with inequalities

Tags: complex, plotting

I need to plot the function where z is a complex number:

$$S = {z:|z + 0.15|<0.6} \wedge {z:Pi/4<=arg(z)<=Pi}$$

I can do this:

```
RegionPlot[{Norm[x + y + 1.5] < 0.6}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

But it does not bound it by `{z:Pi/4<=arg(z)<=Pi}`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Closely related: [30687](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30687/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RegionPlot[
 Norm[x + I y + .15] < 0.6 && Pi/4. <= Arg[x + I y] <= Pi, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -.1, 1}, 
 GridLines -> {{-.15}, {0}}, 
 PlotPoints -> 60, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]