# Image of the horizontal lines in the upper half plane under $f(z)=\frac{i-z}{i+z}$?

Tags: plotting, complex, visualization

I would like to visualize the complex function $f(z)=\dfrac{i-z}{i+z}$ by plotting the images of different horizontal lines in the upper half plane under this map.

With the following code

```
f[z_] := (I - z)/(I + z);
ParametricPlot[{Re[f[x + I*2]], Im[f[x + I*2]]}, {x, -100, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}]
```

I am able to plot the image of one horizontal line. How can I do it for multiple ones in one graph?

---

The following code makes the plot rather ugly:

```
ParametricPlot[{Re[f[x + I*y]], Im[f[x + I*y]]}, {x, -100, 100}, {y,0,4}
     PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}]
```

I'm wondering how I can plot it for "discrete" range: e.g. `{y,{0,1,2,3,3.5}}`.

I have also read a related question [Image of first quadrant under $f(z)=(z+i)/(z-i)$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20634/664), the answers of which seem not to be very helpful here.

Comment: The related question mentioned in the OP doesn't seem to be very helpful here however another post mentioned in the link certainly does answer your question [Plotting complex numbers as an Argand Diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-complex-numbers-as-an-argand-diagram?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Artes: That's for discrete points. Do you have a comment for how to generalize it for several lines?

Comment: Read carefully [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-complex-numbers-as-an-argand-diagram/15643#15643), there I draw images of lines under an analogous mapping, just substitute your mapping and that'll be done.

Comment: @Artes: Thanks for pointing that out. It is much more advanced than I expected. I thought there could be a quick fix of my code to get what I want. Anyway, I'm still slowly reading your answer. I shall come back later when I figure out what's really going on: the animation there is impressed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your code to plot multiple versions using `Show`. Here it is over the range 1 to 8.

```
f[z_] := (I - z)/(I + z);
Show[ParametricPlot[{Re[f[x + I*#]], Im[f[x + I*#]]}, {x, -100, 100}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}] & /@ Range[1, 8]]
```

[image]

If you are finding the Map/Slot confusing, you can accomplish the same thing using Table:

```
Show[Table[ParametricPlot[{Re[f[x + I*i]], Im[f[x + I*i]]}, {x, -100, 100}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}], {i, 1, 8}]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful! I'm trying to fully understand your code. Would you elaborate what `& /@ Range[1, 8]` does? (I can see that `Range[1,8]` gives an array from 1 to 8.)

Comment: Look up Map (for which /@ is the shortcut) and Slot. Basically, the Slot # is filled with each element of the Range (i..e, the slotted variable is mapped over the range). The symbol & is needed to indicate the completion of the Slot.