# Arbitrary shape GridGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, lattices

There is a function [GridGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridGraph.html) that generates a finite square lattice graph. Is there a way to make a generalized solution (e.g. with hexagons, or triangles instead of squares)?

To put it in more strict form, I need a subgraph of a finite lattice where each vertex have exactly *n* neighbors, except a set of "boudary vertices" **B**. Vertices from **B** can will have less than *n* adjacent edges. One can think of boundary vertices as a [periphery](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphPeriphery.html) of the graph.

As you can see from my explanation, I have some difficulties with strict mathematical description of my problem, and I think this is why I am struggling so much trying to solve it. Here is what I've tried so far:

- NestList, where on each step I am taking one of the boundary vertices *bv* and adding a few vertices, so that *bv* is not in the periphery anymore, and new vertices are taking its place. I've realized that it this approach is dependent in a way I am selecting vertices from the periphery and extremely sensitive to a starting graph.
- Generating coordinates for a vertices in $R^2$, and then building a [Unit Disk Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk_graph). This was an interesting experiment by itself, however, I wasn't able to provide an algo for putting points in the right places.
- Randomly connecting vertices in a graph with no edges while their power is less than *n*. Obviously, I've got crazy graphs that were not even close to a regular lattice.

There is a [solution for hex grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61834/how-to-create-an-hexagonal-lattice-structure), that could be used together with a unit disk graph method described above.

Comment: Do you mean to do this for general $n$, not just for those $n$ for which it is possible to embed a regular lattice in a plane?

Comment: Yes, I do not care about regularity.

Comment: For $n=3$ you can also use `KaryTree[31, 2]` except with the root node branching out into 3 instead of 2.  Each node has 3 neighbours, except the leaves (the boundary).  Is this an acceptable solution?  If not, why not?

Comment: @Szabolcs , that's a good one! It fits perfectly into my description, but doesn't fit my problem. It isn't possible to generate a square lattice as in GridGraph, or a triangular lattice like this one: http://www.collegedelussac.fr/IMG/jpg/triangle.jpg

Comment: I think, I can post this requirement as this:

If $a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$ and $b_2$ are vertices. $a_1$ is adjacent $b_1$, $a_1$ adjacent to $a_2$, and $b_1$ is adjacent to $b_2$. Then there should be a path connecting $a_2$ and $b_2$, with length $<=\frac n2$. And this path doesn't include $a_1$ and $b_1$.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to ask for help at Math.SE with formulating the question precisely.  Interesting question BTW!  I do wonder what graphs are possible that satisfy your requirement and are also symmetric in the sense that the neighbourhood of any vertex looks the same.  (That's also true for the tree: the neighbourhood of any of them looks the same.)  Unfortunately I have no time to think about it right now, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: By the way, calling boundary vertices a periphery of the graph is a bit misleading. Mathematica has a `GraphPeriphery` function, which by definition doesn't actually return the intuitive boundary under consideration, for example in the case of a `GridGraph` in general. But what the intuitive "boundary" of such regular planar graphs should be actually called?

Comment: @kirma, yes, graph periphery is just a vertices with highest eccentricity. It could be the same as an 'intuitive periphery' **IP** (like in wheel graph). I would define an **IP** as a cycle where all vertices have power less than some n. In the context of the problem, there should be no more than one **IP**.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Yes, neighborhood should be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Admittedly the implementation below is not as simple or efficient as I wished. Some of the visualizations are a bit messy, but I *think* it works correctly.

Basically it tracks the planar graph boundary and tries to add new edges in regularity-admitting locations. Regular planar tilings are trivially present, but this code also generates Platonic graphs corresponding to regular Platonic polyhedra (these close on themselves, and don't have a "boundary"), and graphs corresponding to tilings in hyperbolic geometry.

```
Module[{regularGraphBoundary, takeClosestVertexGroup, 
  selectAdmissableArcs, addNewEdges, tryAddPolygon},
 regularGraphBoundary[g_Graph, nvertices_Integer] :=
  Graph[First /@
    Select[Tally[Sort /@ Flatten@FindCycle[g, {nvertices}, All]], 
     Last@# == 1 &]];

 takeClosestVertexGroup[g_Graph, groups_List] :=
  First@TakeSmallestBy[
    groups, Min[GraphDistance[g, 1, #] & /@ #] &, 1];

 selectAdmissableArcs[g_Graph, candidates_List, nvertices_Integer, 
   targetdegree_Integer] :=
  Select[
   candidates,
   VertexDegree[g, First@#] < targetdegree &&
     And @@ (VertexDegree[g, #] == targetdegree & /@ #[[2 ;; -2]]) && 
     VertexDegree[g, Last@#] < targetdegree &];

 addNewEdges[g_Graph, oldvertices_List, nvertices_Integer] :=
  GraphUnion[g,
   Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@
     Partition[{First@oldvertices,
       Sequence @@ (Unique[] & /@ 
          Range[nvertices - Length@oldvertices]),
       Last@oldvertices},
      2, 1]]];

 tryAddPolygon[g_Graph, vertices_Integer, targetdegree_Integer] :=
  Module[{graphboundary, admissablearcgroups},
   graphboundary = regularGraphBoundary[g, vertices];

   If[EmptyGraphQ@graphboundary,
    g,

    admissablearcgroups =
     Flatten[
      Table[
       selectAdmissableArcs[g, 
        Partition[First /@ First@FindCycle@graphboundary, n, 1, 1],
        vertices, targetdegree],
       {n, vertices, 2, -1}],
      1];

    addNewEdges[
     g, takeClosestVertexGroup[g, admissablearcgroups], vertices]]];

 Grid[Table[
   HighlightGraph[#, regularGraphBoundary[#, v]] &@
    Nest[tryAddPolygon[#, v, d] &, CycleGraph[v], 150], {v, 3, 7}, {d, 
    3, 7}], Frame -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's cool. I have a feeling that it could be optimised somewhere.

BTW, for those who like me don't have `TakeSmallestBy` you can copy-paste it here:



`TakeSmallestBy[l_,f_,n_Integer]:=Take[SortBy[l,f],Min[n,Length[l]]];
TakeSmallestBy[f_,n_Integer]:=TakeSmallestBy[#,f,n]&;`

Comment: @Alexander I'm quite convinced the primary source of inefficiency in my code consists of use of `FindCycle[..., All]` in `regularGraphBoundary`. This function clearly has nasty run-time complexity; if a more efficient method (probably based on progress of boundary augmentation) would be used, this code would be much more scalable. I usually aim for intelligibility instead of efficiency; In this case, finding those steps actually creating valid graphs wasn't that clear (at least to me).

Comment: A related Wolfram Function Repository function: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RegularHyperbolicTilingGraph/

Answer (score 2):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) now has some new lattice graph generation features that might be useful (though not every graph of the type you describe can be generated through these functions).

Here's a demo through a few examples:

```
IGTriangularLattice[5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
IGTriangularLattice[{4, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
IGBetheLattice[5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is `IGLatticeMesh` which uses (a post-processed version of) Mathematica's built-in periodic tiling data to generate various meshes. These can be converted to graphs using `IGMeshGraph`, or to face-face adjacency graphs (i.e. the dual) using `IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 2, VertexCoordinates -> Automatic]`.

```
IGLatticeMesh["Hexagonal"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
IGLatticeMesh["Hexagonal", {3, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
IGLatticeMesh["Hexagonal", Polygon@CirclePoints[4, 6]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
IGLatticeMesh["Trihexagonal"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Convert to graphs:

```
IGMeshGraph[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[%%, 2, VertexCoordinates -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this last graph, not all non-boundary vertices have the same number of neighbours. I included it as an illustration of how to extract the dual lattice, which may be useful for some other tilings.